# how to download YouTube video to Google Drive Directly?

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api, download

I want to download YouTube videos to directly save in my google drive rather than downloading it to local hard drive.
Please let me know if there are any website or java code to download.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related to programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow [these steps](http://extratricks.com/save-youtube-videos-google-drive/):

> **Step 1:**
>
> Get straight into Chrome Web Store. In the search box, type Save to
>   Google Drive extension. Click on the first extension offered by Google
>   Drive team or follow this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en). Click on the blue button showing
>   Add to Chrome and click Add Extension. A file will be downloaded, and
>   you will see a message displaying on the URL bar, Added successfully
>   and you would see the Drive logo on the top right side of the browser
>   window.
>
> **Step 2:**
>
> Now open your Google drive account and make a folder named as YouTube
>   Downloads or any relevant name of your choice.
>
> **Step 3:**
>
> Right Click on the extension and then Click on Options. A new tab
>   would be opened. Now, click on the button with the label “Change
>   destination folder.”
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 4:**
>
> Once you click on the button, you would be redirected to your Google
>   Drive account. You would see an option for the YouTube Downloads
>   folder you made previously. Click on the option and Select it.
>
> [image]
>
> **Step 5:**
>
> In the next step, drive directly to the official website of YouTube
>   and open your favorite video you want to save on Google Drive. Copy
>   the link of the video from the address bar.
>
> **Step 6:**
>
> The next step involves the generation of a download link; users will
>   click on this link to download the video directly. You can visit a
>   website like onlinevideoconverter.com or use an application such as
>   KeepVid to generate a download link. You can use any service relevant
>   to you or you find easier to use.
>
> Just paste the address of the YouTube video you copied on the text
>   field and click Download. You would see download links of different
>   video qualities. Right click on the link showing your preferred class
>   and then click Save to Google Drive option indicated on the menu.
>
> **Step 7:**
>
> Finally, your download will begin. It will take some time depending
>   upon the size of video and your Internet speed. For faster downloads,
>   you can use broadband or Wi-Fi.